# pydantic's `Field`'s default value ignores constraint checks

Tags: python, pydantic

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class User(BaseModel):
  age: int = Field('foo', ge=0)


User()  # doesn't raise an error
# User(age='foo')
```

Why doesn't this raise an error since a string `foo` is passed even though an `int` is expected?

`User(age='foo')` however raises the `ValidationError` as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This connected to the config that you can add to all of your models.
By default the default of Fields are excluding from validation, simply assuming that the programmer puts a proper default value.
However, if you want to enforce validation you cann enforce it by adding a Config to your model:

```
class User(BaseModel):
  age: int = Field('foo', ge=0)

  class Config(BaseConfig):
      validate_all = True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    User()  # Now raise an error
```

Also have a look at the other options for configs in the the docs: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/model_config/